# dojo widget constructor(params) merge config with defaults

Tags: javascript, dojo, merge, widget

I've several custom widgets with dojo. and I am passing properties to constructor. What I want to know how to merge the default properties with the supplied params in `constructor(params)` ? jQuery has `extend()` do I need to use `dojo.extend` ? or `dojo.hitch` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dojo.mixin` will do this.  however, a widget does this automatically.

```
// from _WidgetBase.create(/*Object?*/params, /*DomNode|String?*/srcNodeRef)    
if(params){
  this.params = params;
  lang.mixin(this, params);
}
```

`lang.mixin` is `dojo.mixin` from `dojo/_base/lang`

```
var w = new CustomWidget({a:1,b:2}, node);
// w.a is 1
// w.b is 2
```